# gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: gradle

I'm getting into modding with forge 1.8.9, and I've setup my workspace. However, when trying to build gradle, i get this error:

```
gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Would you mind posting it as an answer? That way other people with  the same issue can benefit from your solution

Comment: What was the problem/solution. It will benefit future readers of this question who run into the same problem as you did. They would benefit from seeing a solution

Answer (score 2):

basically what I did was download a previous version of jdk and java that was compatible with forge 1.8.9. You must also install gradle and set it in your PATH variable. Then, instead of gradlew, use gradle. It should work :)